# Page break using Print Helper extension of windows-community-toolkit

Tags: c#, printing, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I'm using `PrintHelper` extension of `windows-community-toolkit` and printing some data. The problem is when data is large it overlaps the page and i can't find a way to dynamically add a new page and shift data to next page. Is there a way ?

```
public PrintHelper PrintHelper;

public void StartPrint(Panel container, List<CompanyDetail> PrintSampleItems)
{
    try
    {
        PrintHelper = new PrintHelper(container);
        PrintHelper.OnPrintSucceeded += PrintHelper_OnPrintSucceeded;
        PrintHelper.OnPrintFailed += PrintHelper_OnPrintFailed;
        PrintHelper.OnPreviewPagesCreated += PrintHelperOnOnPreviewPagesCreated;
        var pageNumber = 0;

        var data = PrintSampleItems;

        var grid = new Grid();
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() {Height = GridLength.Auto});
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() {Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)});
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() {Height = GridLength.Auto});

        // Static header
        var header = new TextBlock
        {
            Text = "Departments Print",
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 20),
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            FontSize = 18,
            FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold
        };
        Grid.SetRow(header, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(header);

        var dataGrid = new CompanyDetailReportTemplateControl
        {
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        };
        dataGrid.SetValues(PrintSampleItems);

        Grid.SetRow(dataGrid, 1);
        grid.Children.Add(dataGrid);


        // Footer with page number
        pageNumber++;
        var footer = new TextBlock
        {
            Text = $"Page [ {pageNumber} ]", Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0),
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right
        };
        Grid.SetRow(footer, 2);
        grid.Children.Add(footer);


        PrintHelper.AddFrameworkElementToPrint(grid);

    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

The result looks like this.  As can be seen if data is large it is not printed because next page is not added automatically. I can do that be manually looping data and defining exactly how many rows to print on one page and how many on next but that's not what i want cuz if some cell data is large then my logic won't work.

[image: Print image]

Answer (score 0):

Derive from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/printhelper). you could print long `DataGrid` on a separate page, but we still need to manually paging your data in code-behind. For example if we want to cut the data source with ten per page, we need cut the data like the following.

```
private PrintHelper _printHelper;

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _printHelper = new PrintHelper(CustomPrintContainer);

    var pageNumber = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i = i + 10)
    {
        var grid = new Grid();
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });

        // Static header
        var header = new TextBlock { Text = "Custom Print", Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 20) };
        Grid.SetRow(header, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(header);

        // Main content with layout from data template
        var dataGrid = new DataGrid();
        dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = Items.Skip(i).Take(10);
        Grid.SetRow(dataGrid, 1);
        grid.Children.Add(dataGrid);

        // Footer with page number
        pageNumber++;
        var footer = new TextBlock { Text = string.Format("page {0}", pageNumber), Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0) };
        Grid.SetRow(footer, 2);
        grid.Children.Add(footer);

        _printHelper.AddFrameworkElementToPrint(grid);
    }

    _printHelper.OnPrintCanceled += _printHelper_OnPrintCanceled;
    _printHelper.OnPrintFailed += _printHelper_OnPrintFailed;
    _printHelper.OnPrintSucceeded += _printHelper_OnPrintSucceeded;

    var printHelperOptions = new PrintHelperOptions(false);
    printHelperOptions.Orientation = Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintOrientation.Default;
    printHelperOptions.AddDisplayOption(StandardPrintTaskOptions.Orientation);
    await _printHelper.ShowPrintUIAsync("print sample", printHelperOptions);
}
```

Comment: This is what i mentioned that i can doo by looping and manually defining how many rows to print on one page. But this logic will fail if, a cell have large data and that row will take more height (space) in that case data will again cut down.

Comment: Yep, I know that, but currently DataGrid has no api could cut the data automatically. so we need calculate available page count base on DataGrid content height and cell height.